# How to update 2d dictionary values with a new array

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary contains 5 years, for year 2015, dictionary looks like below image, with row,col = 6781:
[2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvfw4.png)
i want to update the values based on another array [22 22 22 ...  2 22  1] size of 6781

I do this line of code:
`feat_landcov[str(year)][col, row] = values`

however, i keep getting index out of bounds error. Can someone help with this problem?

the code to do update is following:

```
feat_landcov = {}
for ith_col, year in enumerate(range(2015, 2020)):
 print(f'Start {year}...', end='')
 st = time.time()
 feat_landcov[str(year)] = np.full(shape=(BOARD_HEIGHT, BOARD_WIDTH), fill_value=-1., dtype=float)
 values = grouped_df.values[:, ith_col]
 print('value',values)
 coordninates = grouped_df.index
 row, col = zip(*coordninates)
 feat_landcov[str(year)][col, row] = values
```

I tried `feat_landcov[str(year),(col,row)] = values`
but its not updating the dictionary

Comment: Please post your data and code (as a [mre]).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.